# View Controller is push by navigation controller show under current view?

Tags: xcode, navigation, navigationitem

In AppDelegate.m : I added the tabbar :

```
[self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
```

In TrangchuViewController.m : I wanted add a navigation controller on top to view thongtinCanhanViewController.

```
- (void) pushThongtinCaNhan:(id)paramSender{
    ThongtinCanhanViewController *thongtinCanhanViewController =[[ThongtinCanhanViewController alloc]
                                                                 initWithNibName:nil
                                                                 bundle:NULL];
    [self.thongtinCanhanNavigationController pushViewController:thongtinCanhanViewController
                                                       animated:YES];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"trangchuBackground@2x.png"]];

    self.thongtinCanhanViewController = [[ThongtinCanhanViewController alloc]
                                         initWithNibName:nil
                                         bundle:NULL];
    self.thongtinCanhanNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                               initWithRootViewController:self.thongtinCanhanViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.thongtinCanhanNavigationController.view];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Setting"
                                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(pushThongtinCaNhan:)];

}
```

But, when start, thongtinCanhanViewController is showed defaulted though i have touch button on navigation. I don't want this.
Beside, why is thongtinCanhanViewController showed under trangchuViewController ? It have to be showed over.

[image]

Please help me note error in my code ? many thanks.